# Download selected packages to a local repository

Tags: package-management, apt, localrepository

Actually I'm a bit new to Linux and I need to download some selected packages (debian ubuntu) to my local repository.

So could you please help me to figure this out?

Comment: You want to install them?

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install package-names
```

will download, without installing them, all named packages and their dependencies, to `/var/cache/apt/archive` directory.

You could also use `upgrade` or `dist-upgrade`, instead of `install package-names`.